# Excel Highlight Entire Row by Column Vaule

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to color an entire row in excel based on a column value, and have it conform to the conditional formatting similar to the one set out in this example. Coloring the individual column seems to be easily done, but I cannot figure out how to color the entire row based on an individual column. I have seen some posts that can do a singular color, but I haven't seen one based on the gradient.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can use a rule based on cell values and apply its formatting to the entire row.

Comment: Can you provide any formula conditions that you've tried so far?

Comment: xxxxx
=$D$3:$D$7

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a dynamic way to do this across a gradient. However, if the number of colors you want to display is relatively small you could define a custom rule for each color, the threshold of which can be defined by the value of a particular column in that row. If this is of interest to you I could post a solution.

Comment: That's rather unfortunate, but yeah go ahead and post that solution, maybe we could elaborate on it to give (255,0,0)-->(0,255,0) for various percentages. A pseudo gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a way to color an entire row based on a dynamic gradient value. However, using a custom defined gradient something similar can be achieved.

We could hard-code thresholds to define when a row should become a certain color, but that isn't ideal for obvious reasons. Alternatively, we can use percentiles to help define when a row should change colors. The percentiles will be based on the `Average` column in this example (which is the D column).

Let's first discuss a custom gradient with the following percentile properties:

- 0-20%    Green
- 20-40%   Light Green
- 40-60%   Yellow
- 60-80%   Orange
- 80-100%  Read

We can now create rules to conditionally color rows with Averages within these percentiles.

To start with, I created a simplified version of the table you provided, including columns `Threads` through `Median` and rows 1 through 6.

Next, I created new rules under Excel's **Conditional Formatting** section. **Make sure that the rules apply to all non-header cells in your sheet**. Also make sure that `Stop if true` is checked so rules don't override one another.

For the rules themselves, you'll want to use the **Classic** style along with *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* options. Set *Format with* to *Custom Format...* and choose the appropriate color for each rule. We will be making one rule per color, so 5 total in this example.

For each rule, you can match with the following formulae:

Green:  `=$D2<PERCENTILE($D$2:$D$6,0.20)`

Light Green: `=$D2<PERCENTILE($D$2:$D$6,0.40)`

Yellow: `=$D2<PERCENTILE($D$2:$D$6,0.60)`

Orange: `=$D2<PERCENTILE($D$2:$D$6,0.80)`

Red: `=$D2<=PERCENTILE($D$2:$D$6,1.00)`

Note that based on the above definitions all rows will clearly match red, which is why it is important to use the `Stop if true` rule option. Also important is that `$D2` is a relative reference to the value of the `Average` column in each row, while `$D$2:$D$6` is an absolute reference to all D rows 2 through 6. If you have more than 6 rows, you should adjust this accordingly so that the percentile is adjusted appropriately. From my testing it doesn't appear that including ranges beyond the actual amount of rows negatively affects the percentile generation, so there may be a more generic way to include all rows.

When you're finished, you should have something like the following:

[image: Custom Conditional Formatting]

If applied to all data cells in your spreadsheet, you should see the rules take effect:

[image: Color All Rows]

This is a solution that can almost certainly be optimized, but it should get you on the right track if you want to conditionally color entire rows based on the value of a column. It is also worth noting that technically percentiles are based on median values (in other words, the 50 percentile is the same as the median), so it may be more appropriate to reference the `Median` column than the `Average` column.